# Delete or Unregister Sharepoint Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Is it possible to delete or unregister a SharePoint Add-in (App) that was registered via AppRegNew.aspx?

Comment: have you tried via powershell? [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ocarpen/archive/2012/08/15/scripts-to-install-update-or-uninstall-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-powershell.aspx) article shows how to uninstall apps via powershell

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with PowerShell. I did it using Windows Azure Directory Module for PowerShell

```
Connect-MsolService
$appPrincipal = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName client_id
Remove-MsolServicePrincipal -ObjectId $appPrincipal.ObjectId
```